# NodeJS / ExpressJS Multiple environments simulatenously

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

My NodeJS project requires multiple environments. E.g. SIT/QA/PROD. I have set up the config files (e.g. qa.js) which specify which port to use and which db etc. My start script sets NODE_ENV according to the environment, and then i launch it by doing "npm start".

This works fine for a single environment, it starts up on the port it should and everything is fine. However, when I then start another environment, the first stops working. I assume this either do with the fact that NODE_ENV has changed, or is it something else? Does NODE_ENV only matter when you first run npm start or after too?

Can anyone please advise how to have multiple environments simultaneously running?

Answer (score 3):

An environment is (almost) nothing special to Express. You can use it as a selection mechanism to set a certain configuration based on the value of `NODE_ENV`, like you're doing now.

Conceptually, you should think of it like this:

```
if (NODE_ENV === 'qa') {
  // set configuration for qa
} else if (NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  // set configuration for production
} else
  // set configuration for development/testing/...
}
```

As you can see, this implies that you can only use one environment at a time. If you set the `production` environment, it will use the configuration for that environment, *and nothing else*.

Running multiple environments simultanously in a single process defeats the whole purpose of `NODE_ENV`. However, you can—to a degree—run multiple different versions of your app, each one running in a separate environment (below assumes that you're using some sort of Unix environment):

```
// start qa version
$ env NODE_ENV=qa npm start

// in another window, start production version
$ env NODE_ENV=production npm start
```

I say *"to a degree"*, because it's not possible to have two different processes listening on the same TCP port. So your environments need to take that into account (for instance, have the QA instance listen on port 3000 and the production instance on 3001).

Comment: This is exactly as I have done.
I have those code blocks for NODE_ENV, and I have different env files (e.g. qa.js) which have different TCP ports specified.
My issue is when I start up the second one, the first ceases to exist. Even when I use a new terminal to SSH into, the same issue occurs. Can you advise please?

Else how else to start new envs, surely this has been done before, there is generally always a need for multiple environments?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by _"ceases to exist"_. Does the process stop or crash? When it crashes you should get a reason why.